# How to prove that a Lipschitz function is absolutely continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, continuity

$f:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a Lipschitz function. How to prove that it is absolutely continuous on $[a,b]$?

My attempt:
Let $\epsilon> 0$. Set $d = \epsilon/M$. If $P = \{[x_i, y_i]\}$ is any partition of $[a,b]$ with $|P| < d$, then $∑ |f(x_i) - f(y_i) ≤ ∑ M|x_i - y_i| = M|P| < M(\epsilon/M) = \epsilon$. Then f is absolutely continuous on $[a,b]$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $|P|$ means the size of the largest element of the partition, the statement as you've written it is not quite true. $\sum M|x_i-y_i|\leq \sum M|P|$, which is $NM|P|$ (not $M|P|$), where $N$ is the number of parts in the partition.

However, it doesn't look like you need to sum over all parts of the partition. You only need to consider one (arbitrary) pair of points within $d$ of one another.